# How can I block annoying SMS From all numbers that start with a specific numbers?

Tags: sms-blocking

I received a lot of spam SMS from a lot of numbers which are started with 60 , so **is there any android app that allow me to block all sms came from any number start with a specific number like 60  ?**

Answer (score 2):

Try [SMS Organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=main.organizer.sms.trailblaze.smsorganizer&hl=en) 

This app can auto-delete messages based on senders phone numer/contact name or even based on keywords in the message text.

The app  lets you set 'rules'to match which numbers to delete. For example, you can set a rule to auto delete any message when the sender's phone number/contact name contains a certain sequence.

[image]

If you are unsure about deleting, you can also set the rule to move all those sms to a folder (This app also lets you create custom folders for text messages) and then delete them from the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [this fine app here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smsBlocker&hl=en) and I like it. But if you go to play store and search for "sms blocker" there are many of the kind, having customer/user comments which are a good idea to read to have a picture of the app.
IMHO always start with trial version and use the one fits best your needs.